# Laggy performance with Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, performance, nvidia-settings

I have gone through various questions and forums but cannot find my question so I'll explain it well here.

Laptop details: 
Alienware M15
OS: Dual-booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04
Display: 144Hz
RAM: 32GB
Nvidia-Driver: 440 (in Additional drivers, proprietary-tested)

Here's the problem.
My Laptop's graphic performance is really laggy when I use the GPU.
In the Nvidia X Server Settings, if I select **Intel (Power Saving Mode)** in PRIME Profiles and reboot, my screen works pretty well at 144Hz, all things are smooth.

If I select **On-Demand** or **Performance Mode** (NVDIIA), and reboot, the display starts lagging, it again feels like 60Hz.

(**PS: I have had this problem on 19.10 as well, so it isn't specific to 20.04**

I cannot figure out why is it happening.
I have tried both with Charger plugged in as well as on battery, but the situtation stays the same.

I also tried disabling **thermald** with the command `sudo systemctl disable thermald` but it didn't help either.

Please help me to get this to work.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is April 23rd, 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: I have had this problem on 19.10 as well!
It isn't specific to this release, I just thought 20.04 would fix it but it still hasn't (LTS might)

If anyone has any workarounds or any suggestions at all please respond,

Comment: Were you still on 19.10 your question would have been on-topic for this site, now you'll need to wait until release for 20.04 support here, however IRC has a #ubuntu+1 room where you can get help for the development release, likewise Ubuntu Forums has an area for development support questions; this site does not - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic